# Assigning ColumnWidths with textbox data

Tags: excel, multiple-columns, vba

I want to control the different column widths of a listbox with the use of textbox input. This is my code:

```
Sub code()

    Dim x1 as integer
    Dim x2 as integer

    x1 = Me.TB1.value ‘x1 is assigned the number 40
    x2 = Me.TB2.value ‘x2 is assigned the number 40

    With Me.listbox1
           .Clear
           .ColumnCount = 2
           .ColumnWidths = ‘’x1;x2’’
           .list = getArray(SQLinput)
    End with

End sub
```

Thanks for any help!

Edit:
The question, to be more precise, is that the code does not work. I am not allowed to write: .ColumnWidths = «x1;x2» So how can I write the code so that is it possible to control these variables from a textbox?

Comment: I'm failing to spot a question in there.

Comment: The question, to be more precise, is that the code does not work. I am not allowed to write: .ColumnWidths = «x1;x2» So how can I write the code so that is it possible to control these variables from a textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
aListBox.ColumnWidths = newStringValue
```

or

```
StringValue = aListBox.ColumnWidths
```

A list of comma-separated values, with each value controlling the width of the associated column. A value can be an absolute value (in pixels), a percentage, a relative length expressed as i* where i is an integer, or an "*" that indicates "fill in the remaining width." If you use percentages, you can use non-integer values to specify fractions of a percent, e.g., 43.52%. The percentage value can be greater than 100%.

Notes

If you use pixels, the last column doesn't grow to the size of the rest of the ListBox. You should set the width of the last column to "*" and it will automatically take up the remaining width of the ListBox.
Without any column width specifications, the headers will be divided evenly. If there are fewer column widths specified than the total number of columns, the remaining columns will divide up the remaining width equally.
An element with a length of "3*" will be allotted three times the space of an element with length "1*". The value "*" is equivalent to "1*" and can be used to mean "fill the remaining space."